# Printing different characters from the one read

Tags: c++, string, fstream, iostream, non-ascii-characters

I'm trying to create a text-based game using C++, just for fun and training. I wrote on a .txt the races of a fantasy world. But when I try to print them into the console, it doesn't print correctly the accented characters, changing them with others. For example, the 'à' is always changed with the 'Ó', or the 'é' is always changed with the 'Ú'.

I tried swapping the characters, for example the 'Ú' with the 'é', but it changes into another character (in this case, a weird symbol which i can't even find, it's like this '¬' but with the vertical line on the left).

```cpp
ifstream racesF("std/races.txt");
cout << racesF.rdbuf() << endl;
```

This is the part of code which reads and prints the file.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: The question is unanswerable without a lot of information about your system and how the console is set up and the precise contents of the file you are trying to read (e.g. the encoding and character set being used). C++ has no platform independent support for international characters.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10

Comment: The file is a normal text i wrote. I can send you a part if that helps L'unica razza non generata naturalmente, bensì nata dai vari esperimenti condotti dal
Non sono abituati ad indossare vestiti, vista la loro capacità di far crescere la pelliccia del loro spirito animale sul loro corpo.

Comment: Having to make some assumptions here but, as you have a number of non-ASCII characters in your data, the text file has probably been saved in Unicode format, with each character being 16-bits. Try using the wide-character version: `wifstream`.